# df.at and df.loc for getting scalar value give different results

Tags: python, pandas

I am following "10 Minutes to pandas" tutorial at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

df.loc['20130101','A']
```

outputs **-0.25092116222457655** in my case

while

```
df.at['20130101','A']
```

results in **TypeError** and **KeyError** at the same time.

```
pd.__version__
```

'0.20.3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.at` requires you to specify a label in the correct object type.

`pd.DataFrame.loc` includes additional logic for string to `datetime` conversion.

For example, this will work:

```
df.at[pd.to_datetime('20130101'),'A']
```

Note that is one reason why `.at` & `.iat` perform better than `.loc` & `.iloc` for accessing scalars: the inputs have greater restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

`.at` doesn't support coercion of datetime like strings to datetimes/timestamps like `.loc` does, you need to do:

```
In[76]:
df.at[pd.Timestamp('20130101'),'A']

Out[76]: 0.18495502425349103
```

The `KeyError` is raised because it tries to match the string `'20130101'` which doesn't exist in your index, your index type is a `DatetimeIndex` and the element dtypes are `Timestamps`

Additionally in the tutorial it shows passing `dates[0]` which is not the same as passing a datetime like string

The docs don't detail the semantic differences between the 2 methods unfortunately